# Exception type details not matching in PowerShell try catch

Tags: powershell, exception

I am trying to find out a way to frame `try catch` block with various possible exception types. I got some clues from other questions to check `$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName`.

However, I am still not able to figure-out where to get the Exception class type that you have to put in front of `catch` keyword.

For example, when I try:

```
try { 1/0 } catch { $Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName }
```

I get:

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException
```

However, when I run below:

```
try { 1/0 } catch [DivideByZeroException]{ "DivideByZeroException" } catch { $Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName }
```

I get:

```
DivideByZeroException
```

Where is `[DivideByZeroException]` found in `$Error[0]` in above case?

Since I can't find it anywhere in the properties of `$Error[0]`:

```
PS C:\Temp> $Error[0] | Select *


PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero. 
                        ---> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(
                        FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(Int
                        erpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction
                        .Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction
                        .Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DivideByZeroException` instance is in stored in the `.InnerException` property of the `.Exception` property value of the [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instance stored in `$Error[0]`, reflecting the most recent error:

```sh
PS> try { 1 / 0 } catch {}; $Error[0].Exception.InnerException.GetType().FullName

System.DivideByZeroException
```

That is, the [`RuntimeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException) *wraps* the [`DivideByZeroException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DivideByZeroException) exception.

Seemingly, because you're using a *type-qualified* `catch` block, inside that `catch` block, the `[ErrorRecord]` instance reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) contains the specified exception *directly* in `.Exception` - unlike in the corresponding entry in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error):

```sh
PS> try { 1 / 0 } catch [DivideByZeroException] { 
      $_.Exception.GetType().FullName; 
      $Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName 
    }

System.DivideByZeroException                  # type of $_.Exception
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException # type of $Error[0].Exception
```

In other words:

- In an *unqualified* `catch` block, `$_` is *equivalent* to `$Error[0]` (the latter can also be accessed *later*), and contains the (outer) exception in `.Exception` and - if applicable - an inner exception in `.Exception.InnerException`.
- In a *type-qualified* `catch` block, you can catch an *inner* exception - as (also later) reflected in `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` - *directly*, in which case `$_.Exception` inside the qualified `catch` block contains that inner exception.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. However, InnerException will not always have some value. Sometimes it is null. Anyways, at-least for this case it is working.

Comment: @SavindraSingh, yes, not every exception has an inner exception. Please see if my update helps.